# Is there a sortable event for "updated but not removed"?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

### I have two connected lists

```
$('#list1').sortable({
  update: function(event, ui){
    //Some code that shouldn't be executed when an element is removed
  },
  remove: function(event, ui){
    //Some code
  }
});

$('#list2').sortable({
});
```

I would like to do an action when the list is reordered (update is triggered), and another action when an element of the list in removed (but update is also triggered in this case).

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tested this but should work:

```
var delete = false;

$('#list1').sortable({
  update: function(event, ui){
    if (delete === true)
    {
        delete = false;
        return false;
    }
    //Some code that shouldn't be executed when an element is removed
  },
  remove: function(event, ui){
    delete = true;
    //Some code
  }
});
```

Set a flag when you are deleting something, when the deleting finishes the update process starts and if the flag is true then skip updating and reset the flag.